# How can I create a new usercontrol inherit from ComboBox?

Tags: wpf

I wanna to create a new usercontrol,it is inherit from ComboBox.I will add some new property to it, and rewrite its ControlTemplate.


Here is XAML:

```
  <ComboBox x:Class="Pesticide.CustomUserControls.ComboxUserControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pesticide.CustomUserControls"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid></Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
```

And here is code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Pesticide.CustomUserControls
{
    public partial class ComboxUserControl : ComboBox
    {
        public ComboxUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

However,I just wrote these code,but WPF throw an error which is "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' to type 'System.Windows.Style'."
What's wrong with my code?Would you please to help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you didn't close your `ControlTemplate`, You also set the `x:Key` as a type. I'm sure that field is strictly used for giving the template a unique Id.

Comment: Take a look at [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview). What you probably want to do is to create a custom control, with a default Style in `Themes/Generic.xaml`. But be aware that the ControlTemplate of a ComboBox is all but trivial.

Comment: I am sorry about missing it when I paste the code into stackoverflow,but actually I had closed it in the program.@Jack

Comment: @Clemens one of my friend had taught me these way,however I don't want to make a control into two different file,one is Themes/Generic.xaml,the other is the cs file.It will make me hard to manage the code.So I am finding a new way to do it.

Comment: you can simply set <ComboBox.Template> instead of <ComboBox.Resources> and you got your thing(do remove the key part...)

Comment: @Milan Thanks!It is the easiest way to do it!It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with my code?

Using a type as resource key is the way WPF handles default Styles.

So a resource with

```
x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}"
```

can't be a ControlTemplate. It has to be a Style.

---

However, it is simpler to directly set the Template property:

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            ...
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for help,I tried it.But strangely the ControlTemplate show correctly in the usercontrol,but do not works when I use the usercontrol in page or window.

Comment: try defining it as <local:ComboxUserControl/> rather than x:Class?, x:Class is only accepted for the root element

Comment: The default Style of course only applies to the correct derived type, so either set the correct TargetType like `TargetType="local:ComboxUserControl"`, or directly set the Template property as shown in the last part of the answer. The preferred way would be a custom control anyway...